# Shared modues with NodeJS and Web Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Sharing modules between Node JS and standard web application.

Hi,
I have a library of classes which I want to use both in a NodeJS and a simple Web page. To that purpose, I created module to export my functions (mode.export ...) and I can call it in my NodeJS code (var func = require("module.js"). However, when I want to use the same module in a Web javascript with the syntax:

```
    <script type="module">
        import { Function1 } from './libmain.js';
    </script>
```

I have an error: Import not found (Function1).

Is this something doable or client and server side can't have commonalities?

Many thanks - Christian

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. What are you assigning to `module.exports`?

Comment: Thanks Quentin for your feedback. I had: function Function1(){}; var func={ Function1 }; module.exports=func;

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
exports.Function1 = function() {
  return "something";
};
```

Comment: While this may answer the question (untested by me), it is generally discouraged to provide code only answers on SO. Please update your answer with **why** this is a solution to the problem (what is the code doing differently than OP's)? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can use it in the same way as node `var func = require("module.js")`,

but you need "compile the code" you can use browserify, it's similar to how to use node modules in HTML

see [Hello World for JavaScript with npm modules in the browser](https://medium.com/jeremy-keeshin/hello-world-for-javascript-with-npm-modules-in-the-browser-6020f82d1072)